# Fallout 4 won't launch after Xbox update

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-4, xbox-one

After the Xbox update on December 6th to version 10.0.25398.2917 I am unable to start Fallout 4 anymore. The loading screen is shown, but nothing else happens.

[image]

As this is the only game I have installed I can't tell if other games are affected. I think it might be an issue with the game saves stored in the Microsoft cloud.

I just started my 5th playthrough so basically I never had any issues running Fallout 4 during the past years. Fallout 4 is the G.O.T.Y. edition with all DLCs installed. No mods.

Anyone else experiencing issues with version 10.0.25398.2917 of the Xbox? Any ideas what to do?

Comment: You are kind of limited as to what you can do on a console.  All I can think of is reinstall the game and if its doesn't work still, you might have to deal with Micrsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the [update to 10.0.25398.2920](https://www.tenforums.com/tech-news/209627-xbox-december-07-2023-update-now-available.html) (installable in Germany on Dec 10) solved this issue.

After applying the update Fallout 4 could be successfully launched.